# Folders in Home appear all over desktop

Tags: unity, icons, home-directory

I have just installed Ubuntu 11.04, and I am surprised to see icons cluttering up my whole desktop. All the folders and files under Home are represented. But if I delete the icons, the folder or file itself is deleted - the icon is not just a link. How can I clean up the desktop? None of the screenshots advertising Unity look like this.

Comment: Was this an upgrade or a fresh install?

Comment: It was a fresh install, from a DVD out of Ubuntu User magazine.

Comment: The error may come from a custom DVD setup then. Try installing using the original CD or DVD image from [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download).

Answer (score 6):

Check the following configuration key:

```
gconftool-2 --get /apps/nautilus/preferences/desktop_is_home_dir
```

If the output is `true`, then set it to `false`:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/nautilus/preferences/desktop_is_home_dir --type bool false
```

then restart `nautilus`:

```
killall nautilus
```

Comment: When I set desktop_is_home_dir to false and restart nautilus, the icons disappear for a couple of seconds, but then they re-appear!

Comment: The flag come back to `true`? In your home exists the directory `Desktop`, or the equivalent as it would be in your language?

Comment: No, the flag remains false. Yes, there is a Desktop folder; I have deleted its contents - the icons o n the desktop disappeared for a second, then came back.

Comment: Check in your user settings if your /home directory erroneously points to the desktop.

Comment: In Advancd User Settings the Home directory is /home/fanie. The Desktop is not mentioned.

Comment: I got an e-mail from Bilal Akhtar. My reply:   I found this line in user-dirs.dirs (without the leading "#"):
#XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"

On adding the "#" to the start of the line, all icons from $HOME disappeared from the screen!

Thank you very much. Problem solved.

Fanie van der Walt.


Bilal's solution:       On 06/26/2011 11:22 AM, Bilal Akhtar wrote:
> Could you check if XDG_DESKTOP_DIR in ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs is set to
> "$HOME/Desktop" ? Seems like a configuration issue from your side
>

Comment: @Fanie, could you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in another comment you need to edit the ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs file.  What I saw was something like this:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/"
```

And I changed it to something like this:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Share"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Then restart nautilus:

```
killall nautilus
```

or

```
nautilus -q
```

Then, open nautilus via Unity menu (press the Super key) or using the run command `(Alt+F2)`